# how to construct a rudimentary function $h$ used in the paper ''scales in $L(\mathbb{R})$''

Tags: set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

A rudimentary function is a function finitely generated by the following schemata:

1. $f(\langle x_{1} , ... , x_{k} \rangle ) = x_{i}$,
2. $f(\langle x_{1} , ... , x_{k} \rangle ) = x_{i}\setminus x_{j}$,
3. $f(\langle x_{1} , ... , x_{k} \rangle )= \{ x_{i},x_{j}\}$
4. $f(\langle x_{1} , ... , x_{k} \rangle ) =h(g_{1}( x_{1},...,x_{k} ),...g_{l}(x_{1},...,x_{k})) $
5. $f(\langle x_{1} , ... , x_{k} \rangle ) = \bigcup_{y \in x_{1}} g( y,x_{2},...,x_{k} )$

For a list of properties of rudimentary functions see for example page 234 of http://www.math.cmu.edu/~laiken/papers/FineStructure.pdf

In Steel's paper ''Scales in $L(\mathbb{R})$'' he claims that it is easy to construct a rudimentary function $h$ such that for every finite $F \subseteq ON$:
\begin{gather} h''\{F\}\times \mathbb{R} = \{ \langle G_{0},G_{1},G_{2} \rangle \ |  G_{i} \subseteq F \ \text{for} \ 0 \leq i \leq 2\} \end{gather}

Please, could anyone give me a hint on how to construct such $h$?

Comment: What does $x_i \ x_j$ mean? What are $h,g$? What is ON?

Comment: h and g are rudimentary functions, $x_{i},x_{j}$ are elements of the sequence $\langle x_{0},...,x_{k} \rangle $, $ON$ is the class of ordinal numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay enough attention to the question, I  was thinking $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: So far I can prove this only for finite functions $F \colon n \to \mathrm{ON}$. What I'm lacking is a rudimentary function $F = \{f_0 \in f_1 \in \ldots \in f_k \} \mapsto \{ (0,f_0), (1,f_1), \ldots, (k,f_k) \}$ or some other rudimentary map that assigns an enumeration with some finite subset of $\omega$ as index set to each finite set of ordinals. (In particular, I can prove that there is a *primitive recursive* function $h$ as desired.)

Comment: Can you please explain  exactly the notation $h''\{F\}\times \mathbb{R} $. What happens first take the image of F then product  with the reals ?

Comment: It is the range of $h$ restricted to $\{F\} \times \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $h''\{F\}\times \mathbb{R} = ran(h|_{(\{F\} \times \mathbb{R})})$.

Comment: @copper.hat: I sometimes have the opposite problem! Specifically, what the hell is $L^2(\Bbb R)$? Is it the second-order construction of $L$? That would just be $\rm HOD(\Bbb R)$, why wouldn't you just write that? :)

Comment: Gabriel, What's the role of the real numbers there? Is there some relation between the $G_i$? Or is it just $\mathcal P(F)^3$?

Comment: @Asaf It's just $\mathcal P(F)^3$ and the reals are there to code subsets of $F$. You need something there because you can prove that there is no rudimentary function $h$ such that $h(F) = \mathcal P(F)$ for all finite sets of ordinals $F$. The rudimentary function that I constructed for finite sequence of ordinals satisfies $h" \{F\} \times ^{< \omega} \omega = \mathcal P(F)^3$ -- and I expect that (if it's at all possible) you get away with $^{< \omega}\omega$ instead of $\mathbb R$ for finite sets of ordinals as well.

Comment: By now I have the slight suspicion, though, that It may in fact be impossible to do with a rudimentary function and that you need a primitive recursive one -- the latter is rather easy to construct.

Comment: We have the $\Sigma_0$ Brouwer-Kleene wellorder of the finite sets of ordinals, which is then also coded by a rud function. If we then look at reals as sequences, can we then take the first three n-sized blocks of naturals (here n is the size of F, i.e. the order-type wrt the above wellorder) in the sequence and let each block index a subset of F?

Comment: @DanSaattrupNielsen I don't see how the Brouwer-Kleene wellorder would help here. You only ever deal with a single finite set of ordinals -- its wellorder you get for free (since $\in$ is rud). But, without primitive recursion, I don't see how to index the set $F$ with natural numbers -- not even with the help of an additional real. I've tried a bunch of things -- none of them worked. I'm not quite ready yet to throw in the towel but I am certainly a bit skeptical about the claim that such a rud function in fact exists.

Comment: Woops yeah, I was mixing things up. In this particular application Gabriel is talking about however (Lemma 1.4 in the paper), it seems like we can assume F to be a finite sequence, as they are $\Sigma_1$ bi-interpretable, no?

Comment: Dan, yes I think that for the proof of 1.4 it would be fine to assume $F$ is a finite sequence, but I am very curious about how to construct such $h$

Comment: Gabriel, you mean constructing h assuming F is a finite sequence? Because in that case Stefan seems to have a solution at the ready.

Comment: Dan,thanks, yes I saw that but I am interested in building that precise $h$ instead of finding one $h$ that works for the argument of lemma 1.4.

Comment: @Dan For this particular application, a primitive recursive function would be more than good enough and using finite sequences instead would also work. But both Gabriel and I remain curious (independent of the application) whether one can in fact cook up such a rud function. I've tried it again for the last hour or so and I think I'm done for the moment... If anyone finds a definitive answer, I'd still be interested to know (you know... for the fun of it).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Notation is my crutch. As a joke, when I was a graduate student (last century :-(), I wrote up some standard ODE theorems with a friend, and whenever a new symbol was needed, we used $\alpha_k$, with $k$ incremented each time (it was in response to an advisor who used unconventional symbols). The results were amusing and rather difficult to read.

Comment: @copper.hat: One of my friends when we took the bachelor course on ODE (last decade :-() decided one time to turn in his homework with symbols instead of variables. So he used a button, a flower, the sun, etc. and when he got back the graded homework there was a plea from the grader to never do that again.

Comment: @Asaf Reminds me of the one time that my professor asked us to implement a certain algorithm in whatever language we wanted. Oh... boy... people surely came up with the most bizarre programming languages ever. Including, but not limited to, brainfuck, whitespace, AsciiDots, ... fun times.

Comment: @Stefan: Fun! Anyone chose COW?

Comment: @Asaf I don't know. I haven't seen most of the solutions -- only the ones we've discussed the next week. It was the first time that I've learned about code golfing. Something that still seems like black magic to me.